# IntelliJ IDEA plugin to fold .conf files?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, lift, folding, code-folding

I have a Scala app built with Lift framework. It has a few .conf files. When I open those .conf files in my IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Fancy Pants Edition, I do not see any buttons to fold those curly braces in those files. Hotkeys do not do it either. Browsed for plugins, none applicable found. Is there any solution to enable code folding in .conf files?

**Update**:
Here is an illustration of what would be lovely. Those "-" and "+" icons do not appear in .conf files:
 [image]

Comment: What format are those files? HOCON?

Comment: @nafg they look like jsons, have .conf extension

Comment: if you mean normal conf file, then they have no code inside, so there is nothing to fold. What _do_ you mean, exactly?

Comment: I've updated my question with an illustration :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The relevant plugin is the [HOCON](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10481-hocon/) plugin.

To [install](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html), click the <kbd>Get</kbd> button from the above JetBrains Marketplace link. Or, from within IntelliJ, go to **Settings/Preferences** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for Windows; <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Comma</kbd> for Mac) and select **Plugins**, then click Marketplace to search for the plugin and install it. Restart IntelliJ to enable it.

To confirm, go back to **Settings/Preferences** and select **Editor** > **File Types**. You should now see [HOCON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOCON) (Human-Optimized Config Object Notation) file types among those listed as "Recognized File Types". Click **HOCON** and you should see `*.conf` under "File name patterns".

All your `.conf` files should now appear in IntelliJ with syntax highlighting and [code folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html).

*Edited Oct 2020 to remove [Scala](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala) plugin reference, as it no longer seems to support HOCON files.*

Comment: HOCON support is now maintaned as separate plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10481-hocon

Answer (score 17):

Those `.conf` files are of HOCON type ("Human-Optimized Config Object Notation"). To enable folding them, you have to force the editor treat them as such. In IntelliJ settings, configure it as illustrated:
[image: Preferences->Editor->File Types]

`Preferences->Editor->File Types`, and there add filename patterns to HOCON filetype.

Comment: This answer is a little incomplete, as it doesn't mention a/the plugin that enables this. For example, the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 5):

## 2020+

The best option is to install [HOCON plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10481-hocon) separately. For now, HOCON file type is not bundled with Scala plugin anymore.

---

*P.S. All credits to [ghik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642314/intellij-idea-plugin-to-fold-conf-files#comment98328346_51902441). Decided to put this into separate answer because I was not able to find the tip at first time.*

Comment: There aren't many things I will upvote with 2020 as the title but this was useful. Thanks

Comment: @Wildcard27 I hope I properly got your irony :D