# How to add .conf files to Pycharm

Tags: nginx, configuration, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I am running a Django Project in PyCharm and deploying it to EC2 in AWS. The guide tells me to use nginx I have to create a file called `nginx_someName.conf` however no matter how much I try I can't get create a `.conf` file and write in it. I tried to download Scala to Pycharm using the question below [IntelliJ IDEA plugin to fold .conf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642314/intellij-idea-plugin-to-fold-conf-files) but somehow the Scala plugin is no longer available on Pycharm. (Scala was supposed to be a plugin that allows `.conf` files)

However I am able to create `.config` files So I named my file `nginx_someName.config` ***Is it the same thing***

> Image below in relation to @yole's solution

[image]
Following @yole's advise related image Reached here now..
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't create"? What happens if you select "New | File| from the context menu and enter a name that ends with .conf? You don't need any plugins to be able to do that.

Comment: @yole it creates a file called `nginx_someName.conf` with a ? in front. When I click to open the file to write in it. It opens a windows pop-up asking me to choose a software to open this file.

Comment: Please go to Settings | Editor | File Types, remove .conf from "Files Opened In Associated Applications" extension list and try again. When prompted for file type, select "Text".

Comment: @yole I did you suggested however after I reach `File Types` I could not figure out how to do the next step =>  remove .conf from "Files Opened In Associated Applications". See attached image above in question I have the professional edition of pycharm

Comment: Scroll the "Recognized File Types" list up until you see "Files Opened In Associated Applications", click it, find "*.conf" in the list of "Registered Patterns" below and click the - button on the right.

Comment: @yole sorry for being so naïve I reached the `.conf` part. which button do I click (see image above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click this button as shown on the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: awesome that worked. Thank you so much for being so patient with me. However just out of curiosity are .conf and .config different filetypes

Comment: There is no single file type named either ".conf" or ".config". Many different programs use these extensions for their configuration files, with different formats of contents, and many of them don't care about the specific extension you use for the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

use .ini instead .conf in pycharm for configuration best answer I can come up with for now

[create a new file with .ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZDY.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).